# Unable to install WebEssentials 2012 for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

Not sure if SO is the correct place for this kind of question.

In order to enable the features for `TypeScript` in my project, I'm trying to install `Web Essentials 2012` to my existing `Visual Studio 2012` installation.

But, it ends up with an exception. The log tells me:

> The extension 'Web Essentials 2012' requires a version of the .NET Framework that is not installed.

Which one is required?
I'm pretty sure that I have almost each version installed.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this issue? I was able to install the extension on a box with .NET Framework 4.5 and VS 2012, but not on another box with .NET framework 4.6 and VS 2012.

Comment: Unfortunately not. 
Ended up by switching/upgrading to `Visual Studio 2015` which has a much better `TypeScript`  integration which makes (at least for me) the use of `WebEssentials` obsolete.